Problema al obtener valor con GetValue<string>
Tengo los siguientes json.
Json de error:
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": "El token del local no es valido"
}

Json respuesta ok:
{
"status": "ok",
"data": {
    }
}

Entonces el siguiente metodo en delphi 11, si la respuesta es ok, me lo coge sin problema, pero si el json es el de error me lo asigna a nil.
Alguien me puede decir a que se debe esto.
El metodo es el siguiente:
function TForm1.ComprobarRespuestaApi(JsonValue: TJSONValue;
  out datos: TJSONObject): boolean;
var
  status: string;
begin
  // Inicializamos datos
  datos := nil;

  // Obtener el valor de 'status' como una cadena
  status := (JsonValue as TJSONObject).GetValue<string>('status');

  // Obtener el valor de 'data' como TJSONObject
  datos := (JsonValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('data') as TJSONObject;

  // si estatus es ok, asignamos al result si no mostramos el error
  if status = 'error' then
  begin
    Result := false;
  end

  else
  begin
    // Verificar que 'status' sea 'ok' y que 'datos' no esté vacío
    Result := (status = 'ok') and Assigned(datos) and (datos.Count > 0);
  end;

end;


Para mi el código está funcionando correctamente. Tal vez deberías decir qué esperas que devuelva esa función en cada caso.
Según tu código, asignas al parámetro datos (de salida) el contenido del nodo 'data' del JSON, y en el caso de error, ese nodo no existe, por lo tanto es lógico que el valor devuelto en ese parámetro sea nil.

pero lo que no entiendo es que si la respuesta es 'ok', el 'status' me lo asigna a 'ok', pero si es error, me lo asigne a nulo, me debería de asignar el string 'error', puesto que es lo que devuelve el status del json
me da el siguiente error:
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EJSONException with message 'Value 'status' not found'.

Recién probé con Delphi 11.3 y 12.1, que son los que tengo a mano, y el código funciona como esperarías (asigna un valor distinto de nil cuando el status es "ok". No estará el problema en cómo estás pasando del string a JSONValue?

Con un Delphi 12, he probado el código y la variable status, só coge el valor correcto de 'error' (Imagen: https://i.imgur.com/DNXVT9p.png)

Solucionado, el problema radicaba en que tambien gestionaba los codigos de error, entonces para el 200 (ok) no habia problema pero para el 400 (error) no entraba en la condicion de hay que no lo cogia.
Muchas gracias a todos
